# Apple loading screen constanlty interrupting on iPad 2 with ios 8.3

Tags: ios, ipad

I just upgraded my iPad 2 to iOS 8.3 and the apple logo loading screen appears all the time as I try to access apps, use the Internet, browse through photos and many times more. That makes using the iPad a horrible experience.

Any idea what's causing this and what could be a solution?

Here is the loading screen I'm referring to:
https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/ipad/ipad/apple_logo.png

Comment: how was it updated (via itunes / 4g / wifi) and  which ipad ?
Also what if any other apps were recently updated / installed (EVEN APPLE ones)?

Comment: It's an iPad 2 16GB and I updated it through iTunes. I had only 2 apps that needed to be updated which I did.

Comment: does iTunes reside on a mac / windows machine ?  try a restore ( revert in this case --using <shift> key selecting to restore (opens a  Open with / save as  style window)  navigate to your pre-update image  as shown here '* https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204215 *'

Comment: Voting to close as *off-topic*, because questions about iOS devices do not belong on Super User. See the [help center](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) for details.

Comment: This belongs on apple.SE as the ios tag description says above.

Answer (score 0):

Update your iPad to iOS 8.4, it contains many bug fixes which may or may not solve the crashing problem. iOS 9 also comes out this fall (likely the end of September) and it is going to put a lot of focus on speed, battery life, and stability, so make sure to update it to iOS 9 when it comes out.